# How to construct a query that shows all procedures inside a procedure? SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able to write a query that tells me all the procedures that are executed within a procedure, even if there are procedures being executed in multiple levels.

e.g.

I have procedure 1.

Procedure 1 runs procedure 2 and 3.

Procedure 2 runs procedure 4.

Is there a way I can get a query for this? I tried to look for it online but I can't really find what I'm looking for.

In Management Studio, if you right click an object and click on View Dependencies, there's 2 options, "Objects that depend on " and "Objects on which  depends"

I need a query for the second one.

EDIT:

I got a query going and this is working mostly. I just need to filter the data out by procedures ONLY. What table should I join on so that I can view only procedures?

```
select  object_name(referencing_id) as referencing_entity_name,
        o.type_desc as referencing_desciption,
        coalesce(col_name(referencing_id, referencing_minor_id), '(n/a)') as referencing_minor_id,
        referencing_class_desc,
        referenced_class_desc,
        referenced_server_name,
        referenced_database_name,
        referenced_schema_name,
        referenced_entity_name,
        coalesce(col_name(referenced_id, referenced_minor_id), '(n/a)') as referenced_column_name,
        is_caller_dependent,
        is_ambiguous
from    sys.sql_expression_dependencies as sed
inner join sys.objects as o
on      sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
where   referencing_id = object_id(N'dbo.npc_sp_par_calc_MinMax')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive CTE.

Something like the below ([demo](http://rextester.com/KNMU99139))

```
WITH R
     AS (SELECT referenced_id                                          AS referencing_id,
                referenced_id                                          AS referenced_id,
                CAST(CONCAT('/', referenced_id, '/') AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS referenced_id_path,
                OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_id)                      AS referenced_schema_name,
                OBJECT_NAME(referenced_id)                             AS referenced_entity_name
         FROM   (VALUES (OBJECT_ID('P1'))) V(referenced_id) /*Anchor element*/
         UNION ALL
         SELECT sed.referencing_id,
                CA.referenced_id,
                CAST(CONCAT(R.referenced_id_path, CA.referenced_id, '/')AS VARCHAR(8000)),
                sed.referenced_schema_name,
                sed.referenced_entity_name
         FROM   sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed
                INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
                  ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
                INNER JOIN R
                  ON sed.referencing_id = OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(R.referenced_schema_name + '.', R.referenced_entity_name))
                CROSS APPLY (SELECT OBJECT_ID(CONCAT(sed.referenced_schema_name + '.', sed.referenced_entity_name))) CA(referenced_id)
         WHERE  o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
                AND R.referenced_id_path NOT LIKE CONCAT('%/', CA.referenced_id, '/%'))
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referenced_id),
       OBJECT_NAME(referenced_id),
       referenced_id,
       referenced_id_path
FROM   R
```